# MYSQL substring with delimiters

Tags: mysql, regex, select, substring

Assuming I have a table that returns set of values,

```
+--------------------------+
|         MyColumn         |
+--------------------------+
| some string 929190. here |
| basic 092019. test       |
| lorem i 092988.          |
| 029109magic. lorem ipsum |
+--------------------------+
```

what i need to do is select from that table with the following rules
1)if the number has space in front and ends with a "." get the number and remove the remaining values
2)get the text after "." and place it to a new column

```
+--------------------------+-------------+
|         MyColumn         |   string    |
+--------------------------+-------------+
| 929190                   | here        |
| 092019                   | test        |
| 092988                   |             |
| 029109magic              | lorem ipsum |
+--------------------------+-------------+
```

I managed to do one, but its only good for a specific case.

```
select (CASE
    WHEN MyColumn REGEXP '([0-9]{7}.$)' THEN SUBSTR(MyColumn, 8, 6)
    ) from TableTest
```

any other workaround or shortcut? I might end up declaring all possible scenarios?

Comment: well it worked for me without escaping the dot. thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Item 2:

```
UPDATE tbl
     SET string = SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycol, '.', -1),
         mycol  = SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycol, '.',  1) ;
```

Item 1 cannot be done in MySQL, but probably can be done with MariaDB and its `REGEXP_REPLACE` or `REGEXP_SUBSTR`.